# How to remove special chars in python

Tags: python-2.7

I have a python string which looks like this :

```
str='(/|\\)cmd\.exe$'
```

Now I want to remove the special characters and get string in following for,at:

```
new_str=replace_func(str)
print new_str
cmd.exe
```

Can someone help me , how to write this replace_func function.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could specify what exactly these special characters mean. I would guess that str is a regex pattern, in which case you could use its match group to get the string it matches.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex  you can remove special characters

Here is a regex to match a string of characters that are not a letters or numbers:

```
[^A-Za-z0-9]+
```

ex:

```
import re
str='(/|\\)cmd\.exe$'
re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9.]+', '',str)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
string = "(/|\\)cmd\.exe$"

chars_to_remove = ("(|\\/$")
for char in chars_to_remove:
    string=string.replace(char, "")

print string
```